# Web Api 2: Authorising against custom claims

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, owin, asp.net-identity-2

In certain controllers, I want to authorize a user against a company ID.

For example, consider the following resource:

```
api/v1/companies/1234/orders
```

This should only be accessible by users who belong to company 1234.

Note that I am using OAuth token bearer authentication.

**Creating the company claim** in `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    //...

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

    // Creating the companyId claim
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyId", user.CompanyId.ToString()));

    context.Validated(identity);
}
```

The current **controller** implementation for the orders resource:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/companies/{companyId:Guid}/orders")]
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [Route]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOrders(Guid companyId)
    {
        var orders = OrdersRepository.Get(companyId);

        return Ok(orders.Select(x => OrderModel.From(x)));
    }
}
```

**Where do I authorize the companyId URL value against the identity claim?**

Can `[Authorize]` be somehow used here?

Comment: Why can't you use a custom authorize filter that checks the current principal's company Id claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a custom authorize filter you could use

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

public class AuthorizeAction : AuthorizeAttribute {

    public string CompanyId;

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext) {


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanyId))
        {
            var routeData = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData();
            var myId = routeData.Values["CompanyId"] as string;
            CompanyId = myId;
        }

        var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        if (user.Claims.Any(claim => claim.Type.Equals("CompanyId") && claim.Value.Equals(CompanyId)))
            return true;

        return false;

    }

}
```

You could also decorate your action or controller with below if you wanted only a single company to access a action or controller.

```
[AuthorizeAction(CompanyId = "1234")]
```

Answer (score 0):

See the approach in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs - instead of "scope" you can use your custom claim type

Comment: This would mean having to provide implementation in many controllers. Is using the [Authorize] not possible? Thanks

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just pointed you to the code for inspecting an incoming custom claim but if you'd implement as is it would not be very reusable. [Authorize] is not claims aware, however you can always write your own attribute. Example of custom filter doing claims arithmetic: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WebAPI-MultiTenant-WindowsStore/blob/master/TodoListServiceMT/AuthorizationFilters/MTAuthorizeAttribute.cs